# Temporarily Closing Live connections

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an excel file that I am connecting to an Access database and I am using a  live connection to work with the data.

I also have a macro that edits the database (Deletes data and re-downloads it from a separate source) that needs to be run.

Currently, I cannot run my macro as the live connections are placing the DB in a read only mode. Is there a way for me to pause those live connections, run my macro, and reopen them? If there is no VBA code for this, perhaps a good code that would allow me to import query results would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Open connection in VBA, push or pull data, close connection. http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_MainPage.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When linking an MS Access database to an Excel workbook via a data connection, the default mode is typically `Mode=Share Deny Write`, which will cause the Access database to become read-only whilst the workbook is open.

To avoid this, simply change this mode to `Mode=Read` within the Connection String found within the properties of the workbook connection.

Comment: @June7 I believe so, yes - I've used this method in the past to connect an Excel workbook to database tables whose content is repeatedly changing.

Comment: Like a charm! Thanks so much!